# How to Click a button using Script in Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript and trying to make a script in tampermonkey to automate button click.The thing that i want with this script is that it should click the button after page load.
Plus The Button Class,Id and button position is changing after every page refresh and button text is "Start".
**Something like this:**

```html
<a class="btn btn-small animated rubberBand valign-wrapper green" id="zOINDFblRN"><i class="material-icons left">launch</i> Start</a>
```

**Following code i have tried but it seems to not working :**

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto
// @namespace    Munem2x
// @version      2
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-small animated rubberBand valign-wrapper green")[0].click();

})();
```

I ll be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var doc = $(document).find("a");
    doc.each(function() {
       if ($(this).text() == "launch Start") {
         $(this).click();
       }
    });
  });
```

This detects the element being `<a>` and it also detects the text inside of the element. That way different IDs and Classes will not affect it being clicked on the page load.

Another method could be done using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a:contains('launch Start')").click();
});
```

Comment: @Abdulmanan I'm guessing you do have jquery. I just edited the code to change the text from "Start" to "launch Start" because of the `<i>` element inside

Comment: Still not working the page load time increases a bit but it isnt working

Comment: Finally thanks man it works now.yaaaayy .thank you you save my day.

Comment: Bro can i get a little more help?

Answer (score 0):

Just use one class is OK.

```
(function (){
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].click();
})();
```

Or you can use ID instead.

```
document.getElementsById("zOINDFblRN").click();
```

Comment: you are right but there are also other buttons available with the class btn  and it is clicking the one available first.

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer the question @Anson - He states that "The Button Class,Id and button position is changing after every page refresh"